# What is the y variable in tickerplant code function?

Tags: kdb

Can someone explain this function in [u.q](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/u.q) in kdb+tick

```
del:{w[x]_:w[x;;0]?y};.z.pc:{del[;x]each t};
```

Questions:
1. What does it do ?
2. Where is y coming from
3. Any sample calling code ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at this code in combination with tick.q. Note that functions and variables in the u.q script are stored in the .u namespace, per the line `\d .u`.

From tick.q -

```
 globals used
 .u.w - dictionary of tables->(handle;syms)
 .u.i - msg count in log file
 .u.j - total msg count (log file plus those held in buffer)
 .u.t - table names
 .u.L - tp log filename, e.g. `:./sym2008.09.11
 .u.l - handle to tp log file
 .u.d - date
```

You mention two functions - del and .z.pc.

[.z.pc](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zpc-close) is called after a connection has been closed. See the link for information on the parameters supplied.

In this case .z.pc is defined to call the del function with params [;x] each t when a connection is closed. From tick.q we can see that t (.u.t) is a list of table names. From .z.pc definition we know that x is the handle to that connection.

So we call del with [;connection handle] each tables. Within the del function, the table will correspond to x, and the connection handle will be y ([implicit paramaters](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#617-implicit-parameters)).

The code inside of the del function deletes the handle(y) from the subscription list (w - or .u.w) for table x.

There's a lot of information on tick.q available online [here](https://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/startingq/tick/). The FD guide linked to at the end is particularly thorough.